# use HTML code in ionic 3 tooltip

Tags: angular, ionic3, tooltip

I am creating an app using angular 5 and ionic 3
I am using Ionic- tooltip  using reference URL https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-tooltips
I am able to run ionic tooltip using this URL.But When I try to inject HTML in tooltip instead of simple words ,
I am not able to achieve that I have tried using ng-template and other methods but nothing worked.

Here is my code In my page module file(module.ts) I have imported

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import { TooltipsModule } from 'ionic-tooltips';
```

and in imports

```
imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule,
TooltipsModule],
```

and IN HTML file using like this

```
<button  ion-button mode="ios" tooltip="I am a tooltip" positionH="right" 
[attr.arrow]="showArrow" [attr.event]="tooltipEvent" 
[attr.duration]="duration">
              Right
            </button>
```

and in .ts file doing binding like this

```
  tooltipEvent: 'click' | 'press' = 'click';
  showArrow: boolean = true;
  duration: number = 10000;`
```

Till now code is working, But now I want to inject HTML instead of "I am a tooltip" .
  HTML I want to insert is

```
 '<div class="callpopup" [hidden]="index!=0">
 <h5>Aditi Kumar <span>+** *******</span></h5>
   <div class="icon-call">
   <a href="tel:+** ********">
  <ion-icon ios="ios-call" md="ios-call"></ion-icon>
  </a>
   </div>
  </div>'
```

So please someone help how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with the current plugin you are using.

Take a look at the plugin source: [tooltip-box.component.ts](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-tooltips/blob/master/src/tooltip-box.component.ts)
the plugin just displays whatever you send as string.

```
template: '{{ text }}'
```

I would suggest you use [popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#popovers).